# I want a particular <div> value from certain URLs but the following code only extract the data from the last URL in the list

Tags: php, extract

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="w3review" name="my_occu" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) // Check for Button click or not
  {
   include('simple_html_dom.php');
   $occ=$_POST['my_occu'];  // Get textbox value
   $occ2=explode("\n",$occ); // store occupation value in array by splitting it by new line
   foreach ($occ2 as $value) {
   echo $value.'<br>';
   $dom = file_get_html($value);
   $list=$dom->find('span[class="snapshot-data"]',0);
   echo $list.'<br>';
  }
  }
  ?>
```

The URL I am trying to fetch data from is : https://joboutlook.gov.au/occupations/aboriginal-and-torres-strait-islander-education-workers?occupationCode=422111
https://joboutlook.gov.au/occupations/accommodation-and-hospitality-managers-not-covered-elsewhere?occupationCode=141999

I am trying to fetch "All Education Aides" data from the sidebar.

Comment: when uou use explode you create an array, you can use `end($occ2)` for take last value

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and your desired result? It's currently unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: I have provided more details.